# Make sftp-server return a banner/disclaimer

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I am deprecating `sftp` access in favor of a restricted `ssh` based API. I need the `sftp-server` (OpenSSH) to return a fixed message "SFTP access will be shutdown soon", preferably on `STDERR`, whenever someone either sends SFTP commands on `STDIN` or uses `sftp` interactively.

If I configure it via `Banner` property in `sshd_config`, the message also shows up when connecting via `ssh` and that shouldn't happen. Same applies to displaying banners from `/etc/issue`. I only need the message to show when a client connects with `sftp`.

EDIT. I tried replacing user shell with a script that writes to `STDERR` prior to handing over the control to `sftp-server` (similar hack to what Kamil described below in a comment) and after `sftp-server` call returned, but the message wasn't delivered to the caller.

Comment: "If I configure it via `Banner` …" – `Banner` is shown before authentication; the client chooses a subsystem after successful authentication. Once the client requests `sftp` subsystem, it expects messages following the SFTP protocol. You can inject a message (e.g. `Subsystem sftp cat /etc/motd; /usr/lib/sftp-server` in `sshd_config`), but this will break the protocol and the client will fail. My tests indicate that printing to stderr (`cat >&2 …`) doesn't break the protocol, but the message doesn't get to the client either. I think there is no solution, but I'm waiting to be surprised.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I too tried adding content to STDERR prior to forwarding the call to sftp-server with the same results. That's how I ended up here :) Thanks

Comment: It's great you did this research; not so great you didn't mention it in the question. No harm done, but we like questions showing research effort (compare: [ask]) and we like askers making effort. Next time do not hide it. I notice you mentioned your try with `Banner`; it's another research effort, you did not hide this one, this is the way to go.